# Term for words with transposed character order?

Tags: word-requests, terminology, linguistics

Some pairs of Chinese words have the same characters, but in a different order. In English, I would describe such a pair as anagrams . What is the equivalent Chinese term for such pairs of words?

Examples: 牙刷-刷牙；人工-工人；合适-适合.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some are **different meaning words** (不同義詞) created by switching two characters' order

Examples:

牙刷 (n): toothbrush

刷(v)牙(n): brush teeth (刷 and 牙 are two words [v + n])

人工(adj): artificial

工人(n): worker

中心(n): center

心(n)中(preposition): in the heart

Some are **reversible compound words** (可逆复合词). In most cases, the two characters in reversible compound words share similar meanings

Examples:

合适 = 适合 = suitable

愛情 = 情愛 = love

浸沈 = 沈浸 = immerse

鬥爭 = 爭鬥 = struggle; fight

連結 = 結連 = connect; link

Comment: Is there a specific Chinese term used to refer a pair of such words?

Comment: unrelated words = 不相关词;  reversible compound words = 可逆复合词

Comment: 蜜蜂 mìfēng (honeybee) and 蜂蜜 fēngmì (honey) come to mind as well

Comment: Saying 蜜蜂 and 蜂蜜 are "unrelated words" (不相关词) might leave room for argument. I am changing it to  "different meaning words (不同義詞)" in my answer